# Homemade yeast extract from vegetable stock for nutritional properties

Tags: vegetables, stock, vitamins

I am a huge fan of drinking marmite, partly because of the vitamins it offers, as I am a vegan.

However, the price of it is quite high and up until recently I was able to buy a supermarket's own brand version, but they have disappeared from the shelf.

I use a lot of vegetables in my everyday cooking, steaming and stewing, so I am always generating potential vegetable stock.

I would like to find a way to add the Vitamin B12 to my vegetable stock before simmering it down into a paste which I know can be done by adding yeast, but I'm not sure of what would be the best process for doing this.

Would I activate the yeast first with some sugar,
or activate it in my stock?
At what point would I heat it up to kill the fermentation?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Also, I know there are blogs about this, but most of them suggest a very slow process for creating marmite that can take up to tn days.

I simply want to create a yeast extract, add it to my vegetable stock and then simmer it down into a paste.

Kind of a quick and dirty method for the nutritional properties rather than taste.

Comment: Yeast extract is one of those things that you can do at home, but in practice is not worth the expense, time and effort.

Comment: After a re-read of this question I'm still not certain what you're asking. It seems like you're asking how to make your own yeast extract, but then you say you don't want to.

Comment: I always thought marmite was a by product of beer brewing.

Comment: "Marmite" suggests you're in the UK.  Sainsbury's certainly have an own brand version in the small (but not "local") branch near work, because I have a jar of it bought last week.  It's also lower in salt than Marmite.

Comment: @NeilMeyer that's how it starts, but quite a lot happens in between to get the product in the jar.  I've done a bit of brewing and have considered what to do with the leftover yeast, so looked into it a while back

Comment: You could also leave the yeast in the beer and make witbier. A cloudy beer is also an option.

Comment: You can get a 250g jar of Marmite in UK supermarkets for around £2.50 ($3.40 US approx.). I wonder if the OP finds it expensive they may be an expat? We make a jar of Marmite last quite a while not least because it has 10.8g of salt per 100g.

Answer (score 1):

A frame challenge, but if you concerned about cost and getting B12 then I think the critical question is where the yeast is coming from.  If you are just buying the yeast it will be much more expensive than buying marmite, so you have to grow it yourself.  One way of doing that is brewing, and this generates lots of yeast as well as the alcoholic beverage of your choice. THe brewing process generally has a stage of removing the yeast from the final product.  Of course you could [make yeast](https://msmarmitelover.com/2011/04/how-to-make-your-own-marmite.html) [extract from](https://endofsilencebrewing.blogspot.com/2014/05/diy-making-yeast-extract.html) this removed yeast, but it is very easy to just leave it in, and get all the yeast vitamins you could require form you drink.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which TBH isn't very clear in the first place.

Comment: I interpret the primary problem the OP is facing is getting enough B12 in their vegan diet without spending loads of money on marmite.  This answer is providing a solution to that problem.

Comment: It is better to ask for clarifications in a comment. If a question is unclear it is better to wait until it is clear and then answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, a 'quick and dirty' food source with nutrients including sufficient b complexes from vegetable/vegan sources appears to be the objective goal.

I can think of several 'yeasty' solutions; including kombucha, mushroom cultivation, Japanese koji-kin multi stage fermentation, soya and wheat fermentation, wild kimchee and even lambic meads... which all have proven dietary benefit and can provide excellent levels of b-complexes, some also have increased levels of other micronutrients.

Kombucha, for example can contain more vitamin C than many common orange juices, and have more vitamin B2 and nearly half as much B12 as typical 2% milk.

The 'without spending too many days' idea seems counterintuitive; as when making fermented products 'fast', with non-technical approaches and safety measures, may have lower compatibility with most human digestive systems.  Some people eat stinkier cheese than other, I don't judge.

With home level technology, in most cases the only 'usually safe' techniques that I am aware of are slow or 'very involved' methods.  Which, when done well can turn out to be the tastiest 'nutrients.'

Maybe this is not 'The Answer' but I hope this helps.